# ApplePay Server Requesting an Apple Pay Payment Session

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I am exploring tokenized payments on the web and I am slightly confused. The `ApplePay JS` class is first instantiated which triggers `paySession.onvalidatemerchant = function (event) {...}`. At that point event contains a `validationURL` which we need to send to our back-end in order to: `Request a valid session from the Apple Pay server.` My question is, as part of the steps of the setup, we need to declare all domains and sub domains displaying the `ApplePay` button; what about the server's domain that will authenticate with apple apis and request the session. Where are the declared domains where the buttons are displayed tied into the whole interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Apple only displays ApplePay button when you use the same domain that is verified in the apple developer account.

And yes if you are using 10 domains/sub-domains to show the apple pay button then you need to verify those domains on the apple pay account.

For more information, you need to check the following documentation you will get all your answers. This documentation created for both professional and biggers.

https://gist.github.com/jagdeepsingh/c538e21f3839f65732a5932e35809d60